# Convert time delta to float64 of number of days

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series of pandas date times. I subtract them for each row in my dataframe and add a column to get a timedelta between the two date times. I subsequently want to use that time delta to scale another feature. So I'd like to do some division on that timedelta. No dice.

TypeError: Cannot divide float64 data by TimedeltaArray

The last line throws the error.

I tried to run the pd series through a loop with float64(i)

```
#Add column of number of days to next sample
df['daysToNextSample1']=df['nextSampleDate1']-df['currentDate']
df['percentChange']=df['percentChange']/df['daysToNextSample1']/(365.25/4)
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data so we know what these columns look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    nextSampleDate1=pd.date_range(now, periods=10),
    currentDate=now
))

df

  nextSampleDate1 currentDate
0      2019-07-02  2019-07-02
1      2019-07-03  2019-07-02
2      2019-07-04  2019-07-02
3      2019-07-05  2019-07-02
4      2019-07-06  2019-07-02
5      2019-07-07  2019-07-02
6      2019-07-08  2019-07-02
7      2019-07-09  2019-07-02
8      2019-07-10  2019-07-02
9      2019-07-11  2019-07-02
```

---

#### Divide `Timedelta` column by a `Timedelta` of one day

```
oneday = pd.Timedelta(days=1)

df['daysToNextSample1'] = (df['nextSampleDate1'] - df['currentDate']) / oneday

df

  nextSampleDate1 currentDate  daysToNextSample1
0      2019-07-02  2019-07-02                0.0
1      2019-07-03  2019-07-02                1.0
2      2019-07-04  2019-07-02                2.0
3      2019-07-05  2019-07-02                3.0
4      2019-07-06  2019-07-02                4.0
5      2019-07-07  2019-07-02                5.0
6      2019-07-08  2019-07-02                6.0
7      2019-07-09  2019-07-02                7.0
8      2019-07-10  2019-07-02                8.0
9      2019-07-11  2019-07-02                9.0
```

Comment: Thanks, piRSquared. I did it by dividing each of the time deltas by  ```np.timedelta64(1,'D')```

Answer (score 1):

An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have been ideal in your case. You leave out to guess what is inside `df['percentChange']` to the readers.

You can easily *do some division on that timedelta*:

```
pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00') / 1.5
Out[15]: Timedelta('0 days 16:00:00')

24/1.5
Out[16]: 16.0
```

The problem is that you are trying to do something like below, which is a type error:

```
5.0 / pd.Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
```

Comment: percent change == 'super secret corporate stuff'. haha.